# Audio Not Working on Corona SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, audio, coronasdk

I am currently developing an app using Corona SDK which uses the audio API for sound effects and background music. The audio was working fine in the simulator and on Android, but when I tested it on iOS, no audio played.

To check if it was a problem with my code, I tried the sample "AudioPlayer" app included in Corona SDK as an example. Again, the audio played fine on the simulator and on Android, but on the two iOS devices I tested (an iPad and an iPad Mini), no sound was heard. I double-checked the volume on the device and tried all of the available sound formats, but nothing helped. You can found the sample application in the  "Media" folder under Sample Code, but here's the key part that actually plays the sound:

```
--If we are trying to load a sound, then use loadSound
if supportedAudio[ platform ].extensions[ audioFileSelected ] == loadTypes[ "sound" ].extensions[ audioExtensionSelected ] then
    --Load the audio file fully into memory
    audioLoaded = audio.loadSound( audioFiles[ audioFileSelected ] .. supportedAudio[ platform ].extensions[ audioExtensionSelected ] )
    --Play audio file
    audioHandle = audio.play( audioLoaded, { channel = 1, loops = audioLoops, onComplete = resetButtonState } )
else
    --Load the audio file in chunks
    audioLoaded = audio.loadStream( audioFiles[ audioFileSelected ] .. supportedAudio[ platform ].extensions[ audioExtensionSelected ] )
    --Play the audio file
    audioHandle = audio.play( audioLoaded, { channel = 1, loops = audioLoops, onComplete = resetButtonState } )
end
```

Is this a bug with Corona SDK and/or iOS, or am I doing something wrong? I couldn't find anybody else who seemed to be having a similar problem when I searched this on Google, though it seems like playing sound wouldn't be a very rare task. Since nobody else is having this problem as far as I can tell, I'm probably doing something wrong, but I honestly have no idea what it could be. Can anybody else reproduce this problem? Thank you in advance for your help!

**Notes:**

The iPad is running iOS version 5.1.1, the iPad Mini is running iOS version 6.1.2, and I am using the latest public release of Corona SDK (which is available for free as Corona SDK Starter). I also tried the previous public release of Corona SDK, but it made no difference, so if it is a regression it is not a recent one.

**Update:**

I just tried it on an iPod Touch (iOS version 6.1.3) and the sound is working fine. However, I still have absolutely no idea what is causing the problem on the other two devices. Anybody have any insights on what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, which file types are you using? I had problems trying to use oggs on iOS. Like yourself, they worked on the simulator and Android, but not on iOS. So my first suggestion would be to check that the filetype can be used on iOS.
Also, are you 100% sure there are no mistakes in the filenames in your code? I've experienced problems where one platform somehow bypassed a mistake in upper/lower case file names, but another platform didn't.

Comment: I tried all of the file types available in the sample project (".aac", ".aif", ".caf", ".wav", and ".mp3"), and none of them played. The capitalization in the sample project also seems to be correct. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Ogg Vorbis is a royalty free and patent free format. However, this is not supported on iOS.

Beware that certain formats (particularly highly compressed lossy formats like mp3, aac, ogg vorbis) can pad/remove samples at the end of an audio sample and potentially break a "perfect-looping" clip. If you are experiencing gaps in looping playback, try using WAV and make sure your lead-in and ending points are clean.

For further clarification visit:http://developer.coronalabs.com/partner/audionotes

Comment: I tried all of the available sound formats (including .wav), so it is not an issue with any particular one. I was not having issues with gaps in the audio, rather the audio failed to play at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.  It did turn out to be the upper/lower case naming issue.  The actual files name was "song.mp3", was referring to it in code as "Song.mp3".  Android doesn't care about this, but iOS does.  Also, I find sometimes in my windows environment, if I rename the file just changing the case, it doesn't always reflect it.